# iPhone/Android takes forever to load the page the 1st time

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple site in C#/Razor/MVC 4, which has a lot of 3rd party JavaScript libraries (jQuery, jQuery Mobile, Google Charts, Modernizr, etc...).  The site supports both desktop and mobile clients (via the .Mobile.cshtml naming convention).

When I deploy my project to an IIS box and hit it with a desktop browser (Chrome/IE), the page comes up in an instant.  If I hit it with a mobile device (iPhone, for instance), it takes a good minute for the page to load.  But only the first time, after that all pages load very fast.

I profiled the database and it's not it.  So it has to be client-side.  Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Is this over Wifi and the mobile network, or just the mobile network? It sounds like you think loading the resources are causing the issue which I think is very likely. Are they on a CDN?

Comment: Is it slow for all clients on first hit or is it slow for the first mobile client that hits it, but then fast for all others (starting with an iPhone and then moving to an Android).

Comment: @JohnKoerner It's only slow for mobile clients the first time.  So in other words, I could hit the site with a desktop client, then with a mobile client and that first mobile hit will be slow.

Comment: @DaveZych It's over WiFi.  And no, not on a CDN.  I should probably do that.

Comment: @AngryHacker What if you hit the mobile site with a PC and then tried on a mobile?

Comment: Excuse me if I misunderstood your answer to @JohnKoerner's question, but is it slow for _each_ mobile user when they hit it their respective first times, or for _only_ the first mobile user that hits it, and the rest that hit it their own respective first times it loads fast?

Comment: @DaveZych For every mobile user, the first hit is slow.  Looks like there is a way to proxy iPhone to Fiddler, that's my next step.

Comment: @DaveZych Actually, I take my words back.  The libraries are all on CDNs (Google for charts, jQuery site for most of the rest).

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Chrome remote debugging** if you have an Android phone which has the Chrome browser installed. See instructions here:https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging
This should allow you to check the timeline. Maybe you can find more clues in there.

If you have access to a MacOS device, then you could also try **Safari Remote Debugging**: [first search result](http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/)
and check the timeline/console.
Some `console.log` calls in your JS code might help.

From what you are describing to me it sounds like

- either the mobile devices are caching the page+resources, and this takes a long time
- either the automatic view generation from MVC4 takes some time to initialize

You should be able to verify the second hypothesis by changing your user agent on the desktop browser to impersonate Chrome/Safari Mobile. That should trigger the MVC4 mobile generation, and, if this is the problem, it should take 1 minute on the desktop browser also.